# SQL Server 2008 Rank with Nulls last

Tags: sql-server, rank

I have the below extract from a long query that I wrote. I'm trying to create a Rank function to rank so I then can filter with a sub query

How would one utilize rank where blanks and null would be ranked last?

Rank

```
id    Category        Review
 1      Site           "null value"
 1     "blank value"      Yes
 1     Sited            Yes
```

Expected Output:

```
id    Category        Review            Rnk
 1      Site           "null value"       3
 1     "blank value"      Yes             2
 1     Sited            Yes               1
```

Comment: Can you give your expected output? I mean, the rule of which one would go first? Which column are you order by?

Comment: updated question. Would like to see a rank where blanks and nulls are ranked last in  Dense_Rank

Comment: Are you having issues getting them in the right order or assigning them the rank?

Comment: DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY ID, REVIEW ORDER BY Review, Category) Rnk .But I would like the Order by of the nulls and blanks to be last when ranking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Id INT, Category VARCHAR(15), Review VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1,'Site',NULL),(1,NULL,'Yes'),(1,'Sited','Yes')

SELECT
    Id
    ,Category
    ,Review
    ,Rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
          CASE WHEN ISNULL(Review,'') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(Category,'') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    @Table
ORDER BY
    Rnk DESC
```

Use a CASE Expressions to test for NULL values in the fields and if null make it a larger value than not null.  Do this for `Category` and `Review`.  If you want ties switch `ROW_NUMBER()` to `DENSE_RANK()`.  Add partition and other order by information to refine for more test cases.

In your Case Expressions you can do all kinds of things like if you want to sort Nulls absolutely last and blanks (empty string) second to last you could do something like

```
CASE
  WHEN Review IS NULL THEN 2 --Nulls last
  WHEN Review = '' THEN 1 -- Empty String 2nd To Last
  ELSE 0 --
END
```

Comment: Since the columns can be NULL or blank perhaps use `coalesce...=''`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.id
    , a.Category
    , a.Review
    , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.CategoryRank DESC, a.Category, a.Review DESC, a.Review) AS Rnk
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        id, Category, Review,
        CASE
            WHEN Category IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS CategoryRank,
        CASE
            WHEN Review='' THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS ReviewRank       
    ) a
```

Comment: You can use ROWNUMBER() too, depends on the specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you order by desc, the nulls will come up last.

```
DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY ID, REVIEW ORDER BY F.TypeOfReview desc, OnSiteChoices desc) Rnk
```